# Python Selenium: how to scrape results after clicking each record in a table on website

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The website has a table containing multiple elements that can be clicked.

Every click will direct me to a separate page showing additional table results for the respective element.

I want to scrape the table results for all these elements using Selenium in Python (also use BeautifulSoup for parsing html data).

Below is my current code:

```
for i in range(table_pd2.shape[0]):

driver.find_element_by_link_text(table_pd2[0][i]).click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = bs.find_all('table', id='xxx')
table_pd = pd.read_html(str(table))
table_pd = table_pd[0]

driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Below is my logic:

- table_pd2: a pandas series I created including the text of all elements
- In the for loop:

  - locate and click each element in the table on website
  - switch to a popup page containing additional table results
  - get the table results and store them in a pandas df called table_pd
  - close the current page and switch back to the original page for clicking 
    the next item

Problem: 
- How could I save each of the results in table_pd after each click? How could I combine all table_pd into a big pandas dataframe?

Please suggest, thanks!

Comment: why is this tagged as java?

Comment: you forgot to add the website address !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below.

```
all_df = pd.DataFrame() #<====== created over all df
for i in range(table_pd2.shape[0]):

driver.find_element_by_link_text(table_pd2[0][i]).click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = bs.find_all('table', id='xxx')
table_pd = pd.read_html(str(table))
table_pd = table_pd[0]
all_df.append(table_pd) #<====== appending to over all df
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```